# Why Buildroot does not take in account new device_table.txt?

Tags: linux, buildroot

I want to modify the permission of a file.
I created my own device_table.txt in location `board/<product>`.

Configured `BR2_ROOTFS_DEVICE_TABLE` to point to the location of the new device_table.txt.

The permission of the file is not modified.

I can see that buildroot uses a default device_table.txt: system/device_table.txt.

Do I have to do extra configurations to buildroot? What I am missing?

Comment: It seems that the ROOTFS_DEVICE_TABLE makefile variable is not getting the new device_table.txt location. Uses the default one.

Answer (score 0):

Problem found: had a space in:

BR2_ROOTFS_DEVICE_TABLE =<device_table_location>.

Fix BR2_ROOTFS_DEVICE_TABLE=<device_table_location>.